# codeigniter video uploading

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to upload a video.

**My mime config:**

```
'wmv' => array('video/wmv', 'video/x-ms-wmv', 'flv-application/octet-stream', 'application/octet-stream'),
'flv' => array('video/x-flv', 'flv-application/octet-stream', 'application/octet-stream'),
'mp4' => 'video/mp4',
'3gp' => 'video/3gpp'
```

**My view:**

```
 <div id="upload">
        <?php
        echo form_open_multipart('audio');
        echo form_upload('userfile');
        echo form_submit('upload','Upload');
        echo form_close();
        ?>
</div>
```

**My controller:**

```
 function index() {
    $this->load->model('Audio_model');
    if ($this->input->post('upload')) {
        $this->Audio_model->do_upload();
    }
    $this->load->view('v_audio');
}
```

**My model:**

```
 function do_upload() {
    $config = array(
        'allowed_types' =>  'mp4|3gp|flv|mp3',
        'max_size'=>'100000',
        'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path
    );
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {
        echo "Upload success!";
    } else {
        echo "Upload failed!";
    }
}
```

I can upload mp3's successfully, but not mp4, 3gp or flv, they all fail to upload.

Comment: Does `$this->upload->display_errors()` gives any errors? can you output the data from `$this->upload->data()`?

Comment: what ? I can't understand what your means

Comment: go to mimes in config folder and see if they are there and allowed. if not than add them

Comment: I have added it into mime file

Comment: check your php.ini and make sure the file size isn't being limited there, just because you set max file size in your model doesn't mean php.ini itself isn't overriding it. Instead of echo "upload failed" put echo $this->upload->display_errors(); and see WHY it's failing.

Comment: page roytuts.com/upload-and-play-video-using-codeigniter/

Answer (score 2):

Add mime type in the config/mimes.php

```
'flv'    => array('video/x-flv', 'flv-application/octet-stream', 'application/octet-stream'),
'mp4' => 'video/mp4',
'3gp' => 'video/3gpp'
```

and in root folder make Video folder its enough.....

Answer (score 0):

Check with upload path and pass the name of the  to $this->upload->do_upload('userfile') and increase max_size(upload_max_filesize = 10M) in php.ini

Comment: I've successfully uploaded, change upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in php.ini, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma");
        $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wma")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"))

                && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
                && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

            {
                    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
                            {
                                  echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
                            }
                    else
                            {
                                  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
                                  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
                                  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
                                  echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
                                  if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
                                        {
                                                echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                                        }
                                  else
                                        {
                                                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                                                "video/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                                                echo "Stored in: " . "video/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                                        }
                            }
            }
        else
            {
                    echo "Invalid file";
```

Comment: You'd better add some explanation to your answer.